Nx Release working locally but not in github actions
Currently when I run yarn nx release locally i see the changes since the last tag picked up and a changelog file is written like below.
 NX   Running release version for project: my-project

my-project  Reading data for package "@my-monorepo/source" from package.json
my-project  Resolved the current version as 0.1.0 from git tag "v0.1.0".
my-project  Resolved the specifier as "minor" using git history and the conventional commits standard.
my-project ✍️  New version 0.2.0 written to package.json

UPDATE package.json [dry-run]

    "name": "@my-monorepo/source",
-   "version": "0.1.0",
+   "version": "0.2.0",
    "license": "MIT",


Skipped lock file update because yarn workspaces are not enabled.

 NX   Staging changed files with git

Would stage files in git with the following command, but --dry-run was set:
git add package.json

 NX   Previewing an entry in CHANGELOG.md for v0.2.0


UPDATE CHANGELOG.md [dry-run]

+ ## 0.2.0 (2024-06-26)
+
+
+ ###  Features
+
+ - add production environment configuration ([COMMIT HASH](GIT COMMIT HASH URL HERE)


However when I try to run this in a github action i'm getting the following
NX   Running release version for project: my-project
my-project  Reading data for package "@my-monorepo/source" from package.json
my-project  Resolved the current version as 0.1.0 from git tag "v0.1.0".
my-project  No changes were detected using git history and the conventional commits standard.
my-project  Skipping versioning "@my-monorepo/source" as no changes were detected.

And no changelog is generated.
Here is my nx.json config for release and the github action file
  "release": {
    "projects": ["apps/*", "libs/*", "!*-e2e"],
    "version": {
      "generatorOptions": {
        "currentVersionResolver": "git-tag",
        "specifierSource": "conventional-commits"
      }
    },
    "changelog": {
      "workspaceChangelog": {
        "createRelease": "github"
      }
    }
  },

name: Release

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      # ignore push events that only include package.json or CHANGELOG.md files
      - '!package.json'
      - '!CHANGELOG.md'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Fetch Tags
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: git fetch origin --tags

      - name: Enable Corepack
        run: corepack enable

      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 20.15.0
          cache: 'yarn'

      - name: Restore cached npm Dependencies
        id: cache-dependencies-restore
        uses: actions/cache/restore@v4
        with:
          path: |
            node_modules
            ~/.cache/Cypress # needed for the Cypress binary
          key: npm-dependencies-${{ hashFiles('yarn.lock') }}

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: SKIP_POSTINSTALL=1 yarn install # will run `yarn install` command

      - name: Run Release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: yarn nx release


I have tried both Yarn and Npm and neither work in github actions for me. But both work locally
Expected Behavior
I should see the changelog generated through github workflow.
I tried both Yarn and NPM and neither worked. Working fine locally just not in github actions
Issue opened in nrwl/nx as well -> https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/26702

In the checkout step, fetch-depth: 0 seems to be missing. See https://nx.dev/ci/recipes/set-up/monorepo-ci-github-actions.
